Child lWC not all row values being passing over to Parent
I have 2 LWC components.  Trying to summarize all of the Labor_Total_Calculated__c values from the child record to the parent component.  I can see the values in the child cmp in the 'handlechange' but when I look for the values in the 'saveRow' on the parent component I only see the first field.
I am not even trying to save the records yet.  I am trying to summarize the 'Labor_Total_Calculated__c' values and render it on the Parent cmp.  I thought I could use the same logic if all of the row values are being pased up on the on the field change.  That maybe I could iterate through them?

I need all of the rows and all of their values passed to the parent so that I can insert the new rows as records
I need to summarize total cost value from each row and render it as a summary

Parent LWC
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
        <c-child key={row.id} row={row} onsaverow={saveRow} onaddrow={addNewRow} onremoverow={removeRow} projectid={recordId}></c-child>
    </template>
    </br>
    <lightning-layout-item size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
        <lightning-input name="Cost_Summary__c" label="Cost Summary" type="number" value={Cost_Summary__c} read-only></lightning-input>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <br>
    <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={saveAllRows}></lightning-button>      
</lightning-card>
</template>

Parent JS
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api} from 'lwc';
import saveRecords from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.saveCostRecords';

export default class TEG_CostEstimator extends LightningElement {

rows = [];
counter = 1;
@api recordId;
projectid = this.recordId;
@track currentNumRows;

connectedCallback() {
    this.addNewRow();
    console.log('debug recordId' ,this.recordId);
}

saveRow(event) {
    const {row, key} = event.detail;
    const index = this.rows.findIndex(r => r.id === key);
    this.rows[index] = row;
}

addNewRow() {
    let addRow = { 
        id: '' + this.counter++
    };
    this.rows = [...this.rows, Object.create(addRow)];
}

removeRow(event) {
    if(this.rows.length === 1) return;
    const rowId = event.detail;
    this.rows = this.rows.filter(row => row.id !== rowId);
}

summarizeRows(){
    let currentNumRows = this.rows.length;
    if(currentNumRows >= 1){

    }
}

saveAllRows() {
    saveRecords({rows: this.rows});
}

}
Child HTML
 <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
    
    <lightning-layout-item size="8 " large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
        <lightning-combobox name="Cost_Type__c" label="Cost Type" value={row.Cost_Type__c} options={laborTypeOptions} onchange={handleLaborChange} required></lightning-combobox>
    </lightning-layout-item>   

    <template if:true={laborTypeSpecific}>
        <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
            <lightning-input name="Days_Per_Crew__c" label="Days per Crew" type="number" value={row.Days_Per_Crew__c} onchange={handleDaysPerCrewChange} required></lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="4" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-input name="Number_of_Crew_Members__c" label="Number Of Crew Members" type="number" value={row.Number_of_Crew_Members__c} onchange={handleNumberOfCrewMembersChange} required></lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="4" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-input name="Hours_Worked_Per_Day__c  " label="Hours Worked Per Day" type="number" value={row.Hours_Worked_Per_Day__c} onchange={handleHoursPerDayChange} required></lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>    
        <lightning-layout-item size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-input name="Labor_Total_Calculated__c" label="Labor Total" type="number" value={row.Labor_Total_Calculated__c} onchange={handleCostSubSummary} read-only></lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="4" large-device-size="1" padding="around-small">
            <template for:each={hourlyRate} for:item="hr">
                <lightning-layout-item key={hr.id}>
                    <div>Hourly Rate</div>
                        <span>{hr.Hourly_Rate__c}</span>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </template>
</lightning-layout>

Child JS
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import COST_TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Estimate_Item__c.Cost_Type__c';
import ESTIMATE_ITEM_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Estimate_Item__c";
import getProjectHourlyrate from  '@salesforce/apex/EstimateController.getRate';

export default class EstimatorItems extends LightningElement {

@api row;
@api rows;
@api projectid;
@track hourlyRate;

laborTypeSpecific = false;
LaborManagement = false;
AllTypes = false;

laborTypeOptions = [];
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ESTIMATE_ITEM_OBJECT })
objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: COST_TYPE_FIELD })
laborTypeOptionsWrapper({ data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.laborTypeOptions = data.values;
    }
}

connectedCallback() {
    getProjectHourlyrate({ paramProjectId : this.projectid })
    .then(result => {
        this.hourlyRate = result;
        this.error = undefined;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        this.hourlyRate = undefined;
    })
}

addNewRow() {
    const event = new CustomEvent('addrow');
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}

removeRow() {
    const event = new CustomEvent('removerow', {
        detail: this.row.id
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}

handleLaborChange(event) {
    this.row.Cost_Type__c = event.detail.value;
    this.laborTypeSpecific = this.row.Cost_Type__c == 'Labor - Standard' || this.row.Cost_Type__c == 'Labor - Overtime';
    this.LaborManagement = this.row.Cost_Type__c == 'Labor - Field Supervisor & Management' || this.row.Cost_Type__c == 'Subcontractor - Civil';
    this.AllTypes = this.laborTypeSpecific == false && this.LaborManagement == false;
}

handleCostTypeChange(event) {
    this.row.Cost_Type__c = event.detail.value;
}

handleCostDescription(event) {
    this.row.Description__c = event.detail.value;
}

handleCostInput(event) {
    this.row.Cost__c = event.detail.value;
    this.handleChange();
}

handleCostSubSummary(event) {
    this.row.Labor_Total_Calculated__c = event.detail.value;
    this.handleChange();
}

handleDaysPerCrewChange(event) {
    let newRow = {...this.row};
    newRow.Days_Per_Crew__c = event.detail.value;
    let numberOfCrew = newRow.Number_of_Crew_Members__c || 1;
    let hoursPerDay = newRow.Hours_Worked_Per_Day__c || 1;
    newRow.Labor_Total_Calculated__c = newRow.Days_Per_Crew__c * numberOfCrew * hoursPerDay * this.hourlyRate[0].Hourly_Rate__c;
    this.row = newRow;
    this.handleChange();
}

handleNumberOfCrewMembersChange(event) {
    let newRow = {...this.row};
    newRow.Number_of_Crew_Members__c = event.detail.value;
    let crewDays = newRow.Days_Per_Crew__c || 1;
    let hoursPerDay = newRow.Hours_Worked_Per_Day__c || 1;
    newRow.Labor_Total_Calculated__c = newRow.Number_of_Crew_Members__c * crewDays * hoursPerDay * this.hourlyRate[0].Hourly_Rate__c;
    this.row = newRow; 
    this.handleChange();
}

handleHoursPerDayChange(event) {
    let newRow = {...this.row};
    newRow.Hours_Worked_Per_Day__c = event.detail.value;
    let crewDays = newRow.Days_Per_Crew__c || 1;
    let numberOfCrew = newRow.Number_of_Crew_Members__c || 1;
    newRow.Labor_Total_Calculated__c = newRow.Hours_Worked_Per_Day__c * crewDays * numberOfCrew * this.hourlyRate[0].Hourly_Rate__c;
    this.row = newRow; 
    this.handleChange();
}

handleChange() {
    const event = new CustomEvent('saverow', {
        detail: {
            row: this.row
        }
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}

}

@api properties are read only. That means that, for example:
this.row.Cost_Type__c = event.detail.value;

Won't actually write the value to row, because it is read-only.
Instead, any changes you want to make must be sent to the parent as an event, which can update the value.
handleCostTypeChange(event) {
  this.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent(
      'valuechange',
      { detail: 
        {
          id: this.row.Id,
          field: 'Cost_Type__c',
          value: event.detail.value
        }
      }
    )
  );
}

...
handleValueChange(event) {
  this.rows.find(
    (row) => row.Id == event.detail.id
  )[event.detail.field] = event.detail.value;
}


Thank you for the response sfdcfox.
On the child component I am sending the changes to the parent by an event.  The handleChange method is called in the child cmp when a value is updated.  And I can see all of the values for the row in the console.  But in the parent 'saveRow' method I am only seeing the 1 field value.  Is it the parent method that's the issue?   Also, when I want to save all the rows.  Will the updated logic you have send all of the rows/data to the parent?  Is the handleValueChange method in the parent cmp?

@Phuc As I said, the change handlers in the child component are not actually updating this.row, because @api properties are read-only. You must either send the changes to the parent (demonstrated in this answer), or you must create a local copy of the object to store changes in.

ok.  So the field I am trying to send to the parent is a calculated field base don user input of the other LWC fields.  Is there a way to call the method beside onchange which does not appear to be working.  And to confirm.  I will have to send an event for each field I wan to pass to the parent.  How will this work if I have multiple rows?
Thanks

@Phuc Don't use onchange, because those events have to be built differently than CustomEvent; notice I use valuechange for the name, so you would write onvaluechange={handleValueChange}, as in my example. Also, I made the handler generic, so you don't have to handle each field separately.
